# Page automatically go to the top when opening a dynamic jquery dialog box first time

Tags: ms-word, jquery-ui-dialog, office-js, word-addins, javascript-api-for-office

I am developing a Task pane word add-in using **JavaScript API**, I have used below code to create a jQuery dialogbox dynamically using a function:

```
function myConfirm(dialogText, okFunc, cancelFunc, dialogTitle) {
        $('<div style="padding: 10px; max-width: 500px; word-wrap: break-word;">' 
                              + dialogText + '</div>').dialog({
            draggable: true,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false,
            width: 'auto',
            title: dialogTitle || 'Confirm',
            minHeight: 75,
            position: {
                my: "center",
                at: "center",
                of: window
            },
            buttons: {
                OK: function() {
                    if (typeof(okFunc) == 'function') {
                        setTimeout(okFunc, 50);
                    }
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    if (typeof(cancelFunc) == 'function') {
                        setTimeout(cancelFunc, 50);
                    }
                    $(this).dialog('destroy');
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

But when i open it first time to call `myConfirm` function, the page scroll goes to top and when i scroll down to click on dialog-box it again send the scroll back to top then i need to again scroll down, now i am able to click on dialog-box buttons. it works fine after first.

I need to set dynamically text of box and function on button clicks so i am creating it dynamically. I have also test it on Internet Explorer, it's working fine.

Please advice how i can fix it for word add-in.

Comment: How do you call this function? Is it from an `<a href="#" />` by any chance?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No inside anchor click method, i have also use e.preventDefault(); inside anchor click method.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code when you are calling your function :-

```
onclick="myConfirm();return false;"
```

Just add "return false;" after your function name as shown above.

**Edit 1:-**

**Or you can return false from your function as well.**

**Edit 2 :-**

```
$form.show().dialog({
                close: function (event) { event.preventDefault(); }
                resizable: false,
                etc....
            });
```

Comment: I have called myConfirm inside click method like: $('#use-design').on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); myConfirm(params);});

Comment: Please have a look on edit 2 in answer, can you please try by adding close method.

Comment: one more thing when i scroll down to click on dialog-box it again send the scroll back to top then i need to again scroll down, now i am able to click on dialog-box buttons but this issue raise only first time.